# How to hit a method as soon as my IIS gets restart automatically

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-8

I have an application which sends continuous data through serial port on click of go button  and have hosted in IIS .

I have set Auto Start mode to "Always Running " which will restart my IIS automatically but restarting stops sending data through port as i need to click again on go button to start sending data .

Is there any setting where auto re-start of IIS will hit my Go method and sending data can be continuous through port without any interruption.

Comment: Why don't you host this logic in a Windows Service?

Comment: @CodeCaster I have already designed  and developed in Web Application .Now the problem is of  sending continuous data where IIS re-start makes a problem as re-starting needs to hit go method . can i code it in my .Net application this setting where re-starting IIS hits go method.

Comment: Well yeah but it's like asking [_"I bought a motorcycle to transport cows, now why can't I transport more than one?"_](http://i.imgur.com/IDRSi.jpg). Application pool recycles and restarts are the number one reason why you shouldn't host long-running (and especially forever-running) processes in a web server. You've picked the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Yup..I agree but to step up for  resolution  is there any setting in IIS , where re-start can hit my go method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if the current application pool is winding up in IIS7.5 and Asp.Net 3.5+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448839/how-to-detect-if-the-current-application-pool-is-winding-up-in-iis7-5-and-asp-ne)

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute a method when the application pool starts, you could use the [`PreApplicationStartMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute.aspx) attribute of `System.Web` assembly.

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(
              typeof(Starter), 
              nameof(Starter.PreApplicationStartMethod))]

public class Starter 
{
    public static void PreApplicationStartMethod()
    {
         // startup code here
    }
}
```

With this attribute, each time the application pool recycles, this method will be called. Be aware that during recycle, the application pool starts before the end of the other application. See [IIS Process Recycling overlap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525803(v=vs.90).aspx#Anchor_1) for more information.